# dplyr summarize: how to include all table columns in the output table

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the follow dataset

```
# Dataset
x<-tbl_df(data.frame(locus=c(1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,5,6),v=c(1,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,3,1),rpkm=rnorm(10,10)))
```

If I use the follow command

```
# Subset
x%>%group_by(locus)%>%summarize(max(rpkm))
```

I obtained

```
locus max(rpkm)
1     9.316949
2     10.273270
3     9.879886
4     10.944641
5     10.837681
6     13.450680
```

While I'd like to obtain

```
locus v  max(rpkm)
1     1  9.316949
2     1  10.273270
3     1  9.879886
4     2 10.944641
5     1 10.837681
6     1 13.450680
```

So, I'd like to have in the output table the "v" correspondent row.
Is it possible?

Comment: Next time, consider using `set.seed` before generating random data, so that we can make sure we're all looking at the same thing.

Comment: the general problem that you're facing is this: when you use `summarize`, you create exactly ONE row per distinct group from the `group_by()` line. The `max()` line obviously creates a single value (the max), but how do you expect R to know which value to preserve for the `v` column? That's the thing that needs to be specified. in the answers, you can see ways that people are doing it.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
x %>% group_by(locus) %>%
      summarize(max(rpkm), v = v[which(rpkm==max(rpkm))])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `top_n` function instead

```
# with set.seed(15)

x %>% group_by(locus) %>% top_n(1, rpkm)

#   locus v      rpkm
# 1     1 1 10.258823
# 2     2 1 11.831121
# 3     3 1 10.897198
# 4     4 1 10.488016
# 5     5 2 11.090773
# 6     6 1  8.924999
```

Comment: You don't need to sort each group. Simply `x %>% group_by(locus) %>% top_n(1)` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
x %>% group_by(locus) %>% filter(rpkm==max(rpkm))
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're looking for a way to not type all of the column names by hand, and you achieve that by using `across` within `summarize`, like so:

```
  iris %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    dplyr::summarize(
      across(everything()), 
      mean_l = mean(Sepal.Length)
    ) %>%
    head()

# A tibble: 6 × 6
# Groups:   Species [1]
  Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width     mean_l
  <fct>          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>
1 setosa           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2       5.01
2 setosa           4.9         3            1.4         0.2       5.01
3 setosa           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2       5.01
4 setosa           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2       5.01
5 setosa           5           3.6          1.4         0.2       5.01
6 setosa           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4       5.01
```